# Using XmlReader to get all elements of a XML document (streaming)

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to parse an xml document read in from a stream, look for elements and return them as XElements. I was hoping to make a more general reader that would get every element in the document so that I can use a linq query in the calling function to filter what I wanted. So assuming I want to get the "header", "book" and "bookdata" elements from the following xml:

```
<parent>
  <header>
    <data>text</data>
  </header>
  <books>
    <book>
      <bookdata>
        <title>book 1 title</title>
        <author>author 1</author>
      </bookdata>
      <otherinfo>info1</otherinfo>
    </book>
    <book>
      <bookdata>
        <title>book 2 title</title>
        <author>author 2</author>
      </bookdata>
      <otherinfo>info2</otherinfo>
    </book>
  </books>
</parent>
```

I have implemented the following based on code from [Leonard Lobel](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/streaming-into-linq-to-xml-using-c-custom-iterators-and-xmlreader/)

```
private static IEnumerable<XElement> GetElements(Stream data)
{
    using (XmlReader reader = CreateSecureXmlReader(data))
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                var e = XElement.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;
                yield return e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it is called as follows:

```
var elements = from el in GetElements(stream)
               where el.Name == "header" ||
               el.Name == "book" ||
               el.Name == "bookdata"
               select el;

foreach (var xElement in elements)
{
     Console.WriteLine(xElement.Name);
}
```

The problem is that once it gets reads an element as an XElement, it skips ahead and can't look for matches within this element. i.e. I get as output:

```
header
```

because the header is read and returned, (parent is skipped for some reason). But then it reads "books", returns that as an XElement, at which point I assume the XmlReader next looks at what is after "books" which is just some end elements and the end of the document. It doesn't get a chance to look inside for "book" and "bookdata".

In Leonard Lobel's example he passes in the element names that he is looking for, but even if I pass in the name of the elements I want, I still run into the problem where "book" is consumed and it doesn't look inside that for "bookdata".

If anyone knows how I can look at all the elements and return them as XElements, or have a better solution for finding and returning both elements and their child elements, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing leonard lobels method like so(notice the params):

```
    private static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamElements(string fileName, params string[] elementsName)         
    {
          using (var rdr = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
          {
              rdr.MoveToContent();
              while (rdr.Read())
              {
                  if ((rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (elementsName.Contains(rdr.Name)))
                  {
                      var e = XElement.ReadFrom(rdr) as XElement;
                      yield return e;
                  }
              }
              rdr.Close();
          }
     }
```

In your code(this is an example,you implement it your way):

```
List<XElement> myElements = new List<XElement>();
foreach (var item in StreamElements("YourXMLfile.xml", "book", "bookdata", "header"))
{
     myElements.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that but like I was saying it would only find "book", but not "bookdata"

Comment: based on your xml it will get 3 elements-header and 2 books(which contain bookdata).

Comment: Thanks, yes it will. But the solution I am looking for is to return the book elements and bookdata elements separately (though I am aware bookdata is contained in book)